# Integral as the inverse of differential for a multivariable function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to visualize integral as the inverse of differential for multivariable functions and the volume under the surface?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariable_calculus#Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus_in_multiple_dimensions

Comment: @Arthur How to differentiate a multivariable function without using partials?

Comment: There is a good mix between "Who said you need partials" and "You can't do it without partials" here. The theory only uses divergence, gradient, curl and similar, and those are not partials, and technically have no partials in them in any way. However, if you actually want to _calculate_ these quantities, then partials is basically the only way to go.